# Disable vectorization when compiling HPL Linpack benchmark

Tags: linux, vectorization, icc, linpack

I try to compile the netlib hpl linpack benchmark, but I want to disable vectorization.

I removed all optimization flags in the make file and only have the flags `-qno-openmp-simd -no-vec -no-simd` set.

However, when I execute the binary `xhpl`, the walltime and FLOPs are the same as whenn all optimization flags are set and the code is vectorized. Further, likwid shows a vectorization ratio of ~98%.

I read that these flags do not inhibit libraries like MKL from being vectorized. The netlib HPL uses the Linear Algebra library (BLAS or VSIPL) from MKLROOT.

Can I force the compiler to disable vectorization when compiling this specific benchmark and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is expected behavior as the most part of computations happen from withing BLAS or BSIPL which are already built.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I assumed. Simply put, if our system had problems with vectorization and the avx units, we would notice them with significantly less performance? What I tried to do is make one hpl run with and one with no vectorization at all. Is there any way to pull this off without root access on the machine?